# Tkinter - How to change text into an image?

Tags: python, image, tkinter, text, python-imaging-library

Let's take this as a sample program:

```
from tkinter import *
import random
win = Tk()
win.geometry('200x200')

alphabets = ["A", "B", "C"]
rand_alpha = random.choice(alphabets)

lbl = Label(win, font = 'Ariel 30',text = rand_alpha)
lbl.pack()

win.mainloop()
```

In this above program I wanted to change the texts of "rand_alpha" into an image file so that I could use PIL to modify it. Is it possible with python !?

Comment: can u be more clear of what you want? like the image of individual letters inside of the list? and does the below answer solve your problem?

Comment: I wanted to change the alphabets from the list into an image so that I could use PIL to modify the converted image from the alphabets. 

To be more precise maybe I could say changing a string into an image !? 

I want the text "A" "B" "C" in the list to be converted into an image file.

Comment: okay there is actually a way that includes something like making a screen, displaying the letter in high font size and taking a screenshot of that window and keeping a reference to that image. would this be what u want?

Comment: Yes, Exactly ! If I get highest pixelated image of all the fonts and then use that font to convert into an image (maybe by taking a screenshot) then I could resize that image into different sizes. I found taking screenshots of each alphabets cumbersome and wanted to know any shortcut methods by using a python code.

I am using this to make a Vision Chart used by Optometrists. So I will need to resize the alphabets to different sizes (in millimeters) and display it on a screen.

Comment: i guess the below method using `ImageDraw` is what your lookin for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ImageDraw` to create the image you want:

```
from tkinter import *
import random
from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageDraw, ImageFont

win = Tk()
win.geometry('200x200')

alphabets = ["A", "B", "C"]
rand_alpha = random.choice(alphabets)

image = Image.new('RGB', (200, 200), (255, 255, 255))  # adjust the size to what you want
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
font = ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf', size=128) # adjust the font and size to what you want
w, h = draw.textsize(rand_alpha, font=font)
draw.text(((200-w)//2, (200-h)//2), font=font, text=rand_alpha, fill='black')
tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

lbl = Label(win, image=tkimage)
lbl.pack()

win.mainloop()
```

Refer to [ImageDraw](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html) document for how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

I have written an example with `tkinter` and `PIL` modules. I have added several comment to my code for the better understanding.

**Code:**

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageTk
import random

win = Tk()
win.geometry("200x200")

alphabets = ["A", "B", "C"]
rand_alpha = random.choice(alphabets)

img = Image.new("RGB", (100, 100), color="white")  # Create a new 100x100 white image
d = ImageDraw.Draw(img)  # Create Draw instance
d.text((50, 50), rand_alpha, fill=(255, 0, 0))  # Render the text to the image at 50x50 position with red color.

render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)  # Rendering picture to TK
img = Label(win, image=render)  # Insert picture to Label widget.
img.image = render
img.place(x=0, y=0)  # Place the picture to the left-top corner


win.mainloop()
```

**GUI:**

[image: First]
[image: Second]

Comment: If I am correct the image of W and h in the GUI is randomly choosen from the imgs directory and placed into the img Label right !? 

What if I don't want (or have) the images to be imported from the directory but use texts instead (randomly generated texts) and convert the text into an image.

Comment: Okay, I understand what you want. I have updated my answer based on your comment. Now the code does what you described in your comment!

Answer (score 0):

Sure you could:

```
from tkinter import *
import random
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("Yourimage"))
win = Tk()
win.geometry('200x200')

alphabets = ["A", "B", "C"]
rand_alpha = random.choice(alphabets)

lbl = Label(win, font='Ariel 30', text=rand_alpha, image=img)
lbl.pack()

win.mainloop()
```

If you don't want to your image cover your text, you need to use `compound=[CENTER,BOTTOM,TOP,LEFT,RIGHT]`.

Comment: I am sorry but the answer tells me to insert a new image but I wanted to convert the text generated from rand_alpha into an image and use that text as an image.